# how to remove file format using substring

Tags: c#, substring

I am always struggling to understand how substring works in C#. How to use substring in C# to remove the file format?

**from :**

test.xml

**to:**

test

Answer (score 3):

You should use `System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` method for this purpose:

```
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("filename");
```

If you want to use `Substring()` method, you have to find the last dot index using `LastIndexOf('.')`, then perform the `Substring(0,lastIndex)` (of course if the found last index is not `-1`)

Answer (score 3):

Although `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` is the normal way to do it, you can do it with `Substring`. You first have to find the period.

```
string name = "test.xml";
int pos = name.LastIndexOf('.');
if (pos >= 0)
{
    name = name.Substring(0, pos);
}
```

Comment: + 1 for actually answering the question.  The .NET method which is usually a better solution, but it might not be available in some places where Substring() is (.NET micro framework maybe?)

Comment: Downvoter? Something you'd like to share?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use substring:

```
string file = "test.xml";
string filewithoutextention = file.Substring(0,file.IndexOf('.'));
```

Comment: And what happens if the file name is "foo.old.xml"? Or "FilenameWithoutExtension"?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("test.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Substring here, for you can use [`System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[`System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx) should help you.